# Access windows user variables on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I create a user on the server machine and add a user variable to this account.

I now have a login on an aspx page which checks username & password, Once the user has been validated that the user exists I want to retrieve that specific user variable.

Something along the lines of this:

```
string environment = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("server_select", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

The problem with this is that all this reads is just the user variable for the user the iis process is running on? How can I create a windows user object from the username and then read that users variables?

Comment: are you looking to get the user name of the individual who hits the webpage on the network..??

Comment: You'd have to enable impersonation for this and use Integrated Windows Authentication. I wouldn't look to retrieve user settings this way if I were you. Instead, I would look at implementing a ProfileProvider and retrieving values from the Profile.